# How to include modernizr in a library

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I am currently working on a javascript library that holds [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as a dependency. What is the best practice for including Modernizr in a library without interfering with users of the library from including their own Modernizr builds?

Comment: It's more than just the basic dependency - another build of Modernizr can mess up what your build did (potentially).

Comment: @Pointy right, any idea what I should do? Should I just tell users of the lib that they need to include Modernizr themselves?

Comment: Well I'm not sure; I'm not a library author so I'm not an authority. It seems inherently problematic but it must be something that other people have dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Which tests within Modernizr do you require they use?

I would link to the builder with those presets and say "go get this custom build of modernizr. If you already use it, please confirm you have these detects in your build."